# cryptoapi and openssl

Tags: c++, cryptography, openssl, cryptoapi, pkcs#7

I'm trying to encrypt and sign a file with cryptoapi with some X.509 certificates. I want to verify and decrypt this file with openssl.

On windows I think I need to use the `CryptSignAndEncryptMessage` function to encrypt and sign data. I used [this example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a signed and encrypted message.

How can I decrypt/verify this file using openssl? I removed the first 4 bytes from the message since it contained the length of the message (from the windows blob).
When I call `openssl -asn1parse` I get [some output](http://pastebin.com/wiF507bM) that indicates it to be parsable by openssl.

When trying to verify the signature with openssl I recieve an error:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey AlonsoCert.pem -keyform pem -certin -in sandvout-without-4byte.txt
RSA operation error
3073579208:error:0406706C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:rsa_eay.c:680:
```

Comment: Why not encrypt and sign using OpenSSL.  Then you avoid all the 2 tool set issues.

Comment: @brianbeuning I want to use non exportable keys from the windows keystore for en/decryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CryptSignAndEncrypt message seems to use RC4 cipher with empty ASN.1 parameters field and, looking at OpenSSL sources, openssl chokes on try to generate IV (which is not needed for RC4).

Try to use other cipher (AES for example) in CryptAndSignMessage.
Anyway, RC4 is very old, insecure, and obsolete.

Comment: After changing the encryption algorithm from szOID_RSA_RC4 to szOID_NIST_AES256_CBC the decrypt commando works. The decrypted message already contains the plain text message. Now I try to verify the signature of the message. This does not yet work http://pastebin.com/V3YM5aFX. The two things still missing is verifiying the signature and getting the raw plain text message.

Comment: So now output is PKCS#7 signed message, you should pick up the correct openssl command line to verify this signature and output tha raw data.

Comment: I'm trying to find the correct way to verify the message. Do you have any clue on how to do it? I test with rsautil and with cms commandos. Cms says http://pastebin.com/r3WAQYcs

Comment: try something like: openssl cms -verify -in inputdata -inform DER

Comment: Sorry, didn't read previous comment before posting. Looks like openssl cannot find and verify certificate's issuer

Comment: after changing the hashing algorithm to md5 in windows the message can be decrypted and verified by openssl. The last thing I'm missing is: How do I extract the original plain from the pkcs7 message. Meanwhile thanks for your help. -> resolved

Answer (score 1):

Your [ASN.1 dump information](http://pastebin.com/wiF507bM) shows you've created a PKCS#7 CMS output from your CryptoAPI code. As a result you cannot use the basic OpenSSL decryption and verification methods.

Instead, use the [**`cms`**](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/cms.html) mode:

```
openssl cms -decrypt -inform DER -in sandvout-without-4byte.txt 
    -out decrypted.bin -recip testkey.pfx
```

(Note: I've not used this mode before, so I *think* the syntax I've suggested is correct. Either way, this should hopefully be the step in the right direction that solves this.)

Comment: I tried: openssl rsautl -in sandvout.txt -inkey testkey.pfx -keyform pkcs12 -decrypt -out decrypted.bin which only gives me: 3073743048:error:0406506C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:rsa_eay.c:523:

Comment: @DavidFeurle I just noticed the contents of your ASN.1 output and I've radically altered my answer.

Comment: I tried to decrypt the pkcs7 cms message as you suggested without success. Details: http://pastebin.com/x038d3Rx

Answer (score 1):

Try using `openssl smime` to verify and/or decrypt. The syntax is fairly straight-forward but you can find the information here: http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html